# How to force Cassandra not to use the same node for replication in a schema with vnodes

Tags: cassandra

Installing Cassandra in a single node to run some tests, we noticed that we were using a RF of 3 and everything was working correctly.

This is of course because that node has 256 vnodes (by default) so the same data can be replicated in the same node in different vnodes.

This is worrying because if one node were to fail, you'd lose all your data even though you *thought* the data was replicated in different nodes.

How can I be sure that in a standard installation (with a ring with several nodes) the same data will not be replicated in the same "physical" node? Is there a setting to avoid Cassandra from using the same node for replicating data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replication strategy is **schema** dependent. You probably used the **SimpleStrategy** with **RF=3** in your schema. That means that each piece of data will be placed on the node determined by the partition key, and successive replicas will be placed on the successive nodes. In your case, the successive node is the *same physical* node, hence you get 3 copies of your data there.

Increasing the number of nodes solves your problem. In general, your data will be placed in different physical nodes when your replication factor **RF** is less than/equal to your number of nodes **N**.

The other solution is to switch replication strategy and use the **NetworkTopologyStrategy**, usually used in multi datacenter clusters, and where you can specify how many replicas you want in each data center. This strategy

> places replicas in the same data center by walking the ring clockwise
>   until reaching the first node in another rack. **NetworkTopologyStrategy**
>   attempts to place replicas on distinct racks because nodes in the same
>   rack (or similar physical grouping) often fail at the same time due to
>   power, cooling, or network issues.

Look at [DataStax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Without vnodes each physical node owns a single token range. With vnodes each physical node will own multiple, non-consecutive token ranges (aka a vnode), and furthermore vnodes are randomly assigned to physical nodes.

Which means that even when data gets replicated on the vnodes right next to the primary replica's node (i.e. when using SimpleStrategy) the replicas will - with high probability *but not guaranteed* - be on different physical nodes.

This random assignment can be seen in the output of `nodetool ring`.

More info can be found [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/virtual-nodes-in-cassandra-1-2).

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra stores replicas on different nodes in the same keyspace.  It would be nonsensical to have multiple replicas in the same keyspace.  If the replication factor exceeds the number of nodes, than the number of nodes is your replication factor.

But, why is this not an error?  Well, this allows for provisioning more nodes later.

> [As a general rule, the replication factor should not exceed the number of nodes in the cluster. However, you can increase the replication factor and then add the desired number of nodes later.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html)

Comment: I think you're confusing a [token](http://io.typepad.com/glossary.html#gls-token) with a [keyspace](http://io.typepad.com/glossary.html#gls-keyspace).

Comment: Yup, I understand pretty well how keyspaces and tokens work.  Could you clarify why you believe my comment confuses them.

Comment: The thing that got me confused is the "Cassandra stores replicas on different nodes *in* the same keyspace" bit. Keyspaces (well, their data) is the thing that's replicated across different (v)nodes. Hence I thought that maybe you meant something like "Cassandra stores token replicas on different nodes". [as a side note I realize my comment was not quite conveying that].

Comment: Consider a keyspace 'foo' in a cluster with four nodes and RF=3. For a given primary key, you would have three nodes holding the data in keyspace 'foo'. In Juan's example, if you have one node and RF=3, you will have one node with a single copy of the data in keyspace 'foo'.